# Javafx bundle mysql driver

Tags: mysql, jar, driver, bundle, exe

*Hi everybody,*

I've fellow steps of this tutorial:
http://www.blueskyworkshop.com/topics/Java-Pages/javafx-win-installer/

to create create Windows Native Installer and **EXE** with **NetBeans 7.2** to my **JavaFx 2.2** application.
I've used InnoSetup, and installer was created successfully.
My application use **MySql** as SGBD, and it use **driver connector of mysql** of corse, which is contained into **dist/lib** when i compile my application.

**But** when I install my application with my new installer, the driver is not contained into a folder "lib" but directly in the same folder with the jar file, and as result **the driver is not found by the jar**.

My problem is how to modify **build.xml** so the installer can respect the basic hierarchy as like as the base directory.

*Thank you,*